# Como invertir la leyenda

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, ggplot2, visualización-de-datos

tengo problemas para invertir los ejes. Por alguna razon ggplot lee la leyenda en orden alfabetico y asigna mal los valores. El azul deberia ser la ocupacion y el rojo los arribos, pero esta al reves.

```
ggplot(df_combinado, aes(x = Fecha)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Ocupacion, color = "Ocupación"), size = 1, linetype = "solid", group = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Arribos, color = "Arribos"), size = 1, linetype = "solid", group = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Ocupacion_MediaMovil, color = "Media Móvil Ocupacion"), size = 1, linetype = "dashed", group = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Arribos_MediaMovil, color = "Media Móvil Arribos"), size = 1, linetype = "dashed", group = 4) +
  labs(title = "Ocupación y Arribos a lo largo del tiempo con Media Móvil",
       x = "Fecha",
       y = "Miles") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(scale = 1e-0)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Ocupación" = "darkred", "Arribos" = "darkblue", "Media Móvil Ocupacion" = "red", "Media Móvil Arribos" = "blue"),
                     breaks = c("Ocupación", "Arribos", "Media Móvil Ocupacion", "Media Móvil Arribos"),
                     labels = c("Ocupación", "Arribos", "Media Móvil Ocupacion", "Media Móvil Arribos")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid", "solid", "dashed", "dashed"))))
```

Gracias por la ayuda!